# User not able to view table entries oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

I am a newbie to the database and trying to learn roles and privilege in oracle12c. I am logged in as user **dba643** and have following codes.

```
create table test
(
  obj1 Number,
  obj2 Varchar2(3)
);


Insert into test values('1','A');
Insert into test values('2','B');

create user rtest identified by rtest;

grant connect,resource to rtest;

grant select,insert,update,delete on test to rtest;
```

After logging in as **rtest** user and issuing the following select statement:

```
select * from dba643.test;
```

The user **rtest** is able to see the two table entries. However, if the user **dba643** inserts a new record into the **test** table, that newly inserted record cannot be viewed by the user **rtest**. Similarly, the user **rtest** is able to insert a record into **test** table, however, the inserted record cannot be viewed by the **dba643** user. Is there something basic I am missing in this?

Answer (score 2):

Use "commit".

I am not seeing any commit on your code. Without using commit you can see the entries only on dba643 user. After committing records will be available for all user.

Comment: Just for completion: If you don't issue a `commit` you can only see the modification in your own session. Even other sessions connected with the same user won't see the changes.